# How to prevent the user to update the style

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document. In that I have some user defined styles.

For instance, I have a user defined style called "Ram" which will have the proerty of the Font Name as "Verdana" and the Font size as "14".

How can I prevent the user to update this style. For instance, he cannot update the font size as "12". (This is applicable for MS Word 2003 and 2007 versions)

Can I restrict that?

Comment: Save as a read-only?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: A solution might very well be achieved programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it takes a lot of effort. Basically, you can turn Word in a generic XML editor and in this mode, you can restrict what is available. Not something you can do in a couple of hours.

But there is a different solution: If you can make the XML format (`.docx`) the default, you can examine the styles used (you can unzip the file and load the XML in a program). That would either allow you to undo any changed the user made to the styles or at least generate an error report if they did.

[EDIT] A bit of googling turned up "[Style Locking](http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/office2003_word_preview.asp)"; that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template with the styles you want to use.

1. Review > Protect Document > Restrict Formatting and Editing
2. Select Limit formatting to a selection of styles.
3. Click the Settings link to open the Formatting Restrictions dialog
4. Select Limit formatting to a selection of styles, then select the styles you want the users to have access to from the list.
5. Select Block Theme or Scheme switching and Block Quick Style Set Switching.
6. Click OK.
7. Click Yes Start Enforcing Protection and enter the password in the provided fields.
   WRITE DOWN THE PASSWORD!!!
8. Click OK.

You and all users of the template are restricted from using all but the selected styles in step 4. You must unlock the template to make ANY changes. Note that some functionality may be limited such as bold, italic, etc. You have to create and allow specific styles to allow these functions. Even so, you still cannot "Keep with next" etc. on individual paragraphs or selections without unlocking the template.